# Yii, Error in findAll, when called using with() method.

Tags: php, yii

I am having PHP class

```
class SurveyQuestion extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function relations()
    {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'surveyOptions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SurveyOptions', 'surveyQuestion_id'),
        'survey' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Survey', 'survey_id'),
         );
    }
}
```

and in controller, I want to get list of surveys with its options, so I am doing..

```
$this->renderJson(array('success'=>true, 'message'=>'Records Retrieved Successfully',
'data'=>SurveyQuestion::model()->with('surveyOptions')->findAll()));
```

but when this controller method is getting called, I am getting this error..

```
include(SurveyOptions.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

As per http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr, I should be able to get response with options in each survey.

I think, inclue(SurveyOptions.php) should be SurveyOption.php (without 's') but 
I am not able to see what is wrong?

Comment: Looking at your namings - your class might be `SurveyOption` and the file `SurveyOptions.php` (plural) - either change the class name or file name. Or I might be totally wrong. Then elaborate, showing the SurveyOptions class.

Comment: my class is SurveyOption & file name is SurveyOption.php. relations method is automatically created by yii with gii scaffolding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comments, you just need to change your relation :

```
'surveyOptions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SurveyOption', 'surveyQuestion_id')
```

Since your class name is `SurveyOption` and file is *SurveyOption.php*

Comment: thanks, you are right. it is now not throwing error. 
But JSON in console is not having 'surveyOptions':[object1,object2,..]  in json. It is still returning same JSON.

Comment: you could have some mistake in your renderJson function, have you defined it yourself?

Comment: I am using extension restfullyii, which is having method like,

 protected function renderJson($data)
  {
    $this->layout = 'ext.restfullyii.views.layouts.json';
    $this->render('ext.restfullyii.views.api.output', array('data'=>$data));
  }
and in view it is having   echo CJSON::encode($data);

Comment: here it is, Array{"success":true,"message":"Records Retrieved Successfully","data":[{"id":"1","questionText":"Question 1","data":"","multipleAnswer":"0","survey_id":"1"},{"id":"2","questionText":"Question 2","data":"","multipleAnswer":"0","survey_id":"1"}]} ,  Not having surveyOptions, I think I have to dig in more, as I am really new in Yii. so thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: that's happening because you haven't eagerly loaded the related models, use the `together` option of `with`

Comment: like this: `SurveyQuestion::model()->with('surveyOptions')->together()->findAll()`

Comment: Still not working. Also tried with('surveyOptions', 'survey')->together()->findAll() but still getting survey_id in JSON, but not survey or surveyOption object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12615/discussion-between-nachiket-and-bool-dev)

Answer (score 1):

In `SurveyQuestion::model()->with('surveyOptions')->findAll()` use the relation with name defined in SurveyOptions

Comment: not able to get you, I do not have any class/file named SurveyOptions. I think gii created field name surveyOptions as its HAS_MANY relationship.