# YII get model with relationship (how to render Relationships using cjson)

Tags: php, yii

I have a model such as Story.  It has a key that links it to author.  I have the relationship and when i do.

```
storyHolder = Story->findByPK(id)
```

Returns the story, then

```
storyHolder ->author
```

returns the author object.  The issue is that im getting both data sets by themselves I want them combined.  Example returnObject{story{}, author{}}.  I want returnObject{story{author{}}}

Comment: can you tell me why you need that? i mean what is the problem with `storyholder->author`? maybe there's another alternative, to `storyholder[author]`, which could be discovered if we know your ultimate goal of wanting the array format.

Comment: It seems that if I do storyHolder->author it returns the related object however when I return storyHolder after doesn't still contain the author object.  So I have manually make an array store both objects and return that.

Comment: This appears to be my issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054237/yii-error-in-findall-when-called-using-with-method

Comment: can you rephrase this (from your comment): **"when I return storyHolder after doesn't still contain the author object"** ? i didn't get that. Secondly, the relationship between this question and the linked question isn't clear to me, can you maybe provide some of your code, and the error that you see? just the important lines should be enough, to bring more clarity to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if the question is unclear,

It looks like the real issue is not with story->author but with CJSON.

Following the question, in the answered questions comment is a link to a chat, in the chat is a link to this forum post.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12952-cjsonencode-for-an-ar-object-does-not-include-its-related-objects/

I ended putting this in my controller

```
    /**
     * @return CMapIterator the iterator for the foreach statement
     */
    public function getIterator()
    {
            $attributes=$this->getAttributes();
            $relations = array();

            foreach ($this->relations() as $key => $related)
            {
                    if ($this->hasRelated($key))
                    {
                            $relations[$key] = $this->$key;
                    }
            }

            $all = array_merge($attributes, $relations);

            return new CMapIterator($all);
    }
```

Code taken from  benjaminbytheway from the Yii forums.

Just attempts to clear up the issue it appears when using CJSON in your view it doesn't include relationship objects.